# Podio API filtering of returned fields without using a view

Tags: podio

Based on the information provided by Pavlo it appears there is **no way to exclude certain fields** and **no way to include specific fields** from Podio data returned from a JSON Post query. For the purpose of this question, the fields involved are (for example) text, category, date, calc field and others which can be added using 'modify template'.

The best work around is redesign of the app to reduce the amt of field data.

(original question)
Is there a way to limit the amount of Podio data returned from a JSON Post query to include only a few specific fields instead of every field?

I understand how to use a podio view or filtering in the Post query to limit how many *items* are returned, but my question has to do with reducing the amount of data returned for each item by preventing data in unnecessary fields from being returned.

(following is an example of the query I use currently, but as stated above I'm looking for a way to limit the fields returned to a small subset)
Example JSON query:  https://api.podio.com/item/app/14773320/filter
Example JSON body:

```
{
"filters": {
    "created_on": {
      "from": "{date.addMonths(-6).format()}",
      "to": "{date.today}"
    }
  },
"limit":250,
"offset":{props.offSet}
}
```

Comment: Can you please re-phrase your question? It's not clear what you are trying to achieve and what you are getting. Please include examples (that usually helps) :)

Comment: Hi Pavlo - I updated the original query...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `fields` parameter for that.
More details on how it works and how else it could be used are right here: https://developers.podio.com/index/api. Scroll down to **Bundling responses using fields parameter** section.

Most likely you are looking for `fields=items.view(micro)` parameter. Podio API will return then only 5 values for each item:

- app_item_id
- item_id
- title
- link
- revision

Comment: Thanks Pavlo. It appears that the focus of the fields parameter is reducing the number of API requests by bundling, which is different from reducing the number of fields returned.

Eg:  if my App has 40 fields, can this parameter be used to return just fields 1-5 based on their ID? Or text label?

Also: does this sentence, _Use a standard view instead of listing all fields (such as including the full app on an item). Typical values are micro, mini, full_ imply that specifying a team view does in fact limit the fields returned?

Comment: Sorry, there are too many questions in single comment, I can't answer them all. Yes, main focus on using `fields` parameter is to reduce number of calls, but you can also get less information and not more if configure your parameters properly. If you would use `fields=items.view(micro)` you'd see that it decreased number of fields returned.

Comment: We're making progress. Yes I want to get less information. 

If I use `fields=items.view(micro)` how can I specify the exact fields I care about?  I would expect something like `fields.view(micro).fieldID1;fieldID2;fieldID3` would be needed.

Comment: You can't specify list of field to get from API. If you need something like that - consider redesigning your app design and move other fields to another app. Btw: if you need to get only some fields is pretty good sign that your app is too big and it's time to redesign it.

Comment: okay, so I understand it is not possible to specify a list of fields to get from the API. Is the inverse possible?  Can I prevent certain fields from being sent?

Comment: Not in a way that you'd expect (like fields=!fieldID1;!fieldID2). But you can suppress all fields using `micro` or `mini` params, or you can include meta-fields, like `files`, `ratings`, `votes`.

Comment: It sounds like what I want is not possible. Unfortunately redesign of the app is impossible because it depends up a calc field which uses many dabuttonfactory.com images rendered dynamically to allow direct item to item navigation. This calc field frequently exceeds 32K characters.

Thanks for helping me with this Pavlo.

Comment: I've spent considerable time trying all the combination of API parameters, given that the documentation is minimal in that regard. @Pavlo-Podio I believe this limitation should be clearly stated in the documentation, **if redesigning is the expectation from Citrix and no other alternative is provided by Podio API**. Would make it easier to point that out to a client (or 3rd party providing the Podio data), for justifying the cost of redesign their whole set of Podio applications.

Comment: I am also wondering: **isn't it possible to filter by a custom view, rather than just the standard ones?** This would provide the ability to return just the fields selected in the custom view. – At the moment the `micro` view is used (implicitly) when specifying any other view name than `micro`/`mini`/`full` (e.g. `fields=items.view(my_custom_view)`).