# Podio API query

Tags: podio, klipfolio

I have podio data with more number of column, but we need to fetch 5-6 column data through API. I attached column name screenshot. If we need only for example order id, city, country then how to write API query?

[image]

```
/item/app/{app_id}/filter/
```

If it is right, how to write query with selected column name with GET/POST.

Comment: https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-item-22360 and here is the possible resolution for your request. https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203307197-Get-specific-field-values-on-Podio-filter This was the answer given by podio Support.
But it can work only for single item... not for bulk Items

Answer (score 0):

The filter endpoint uses a POST body to filter which records to return, not which fields/columns to return. It is not possible to specify which fields/columns to return with an API call according to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44572506/podio-api-filtering-of-returned-fields-without-using-a-view#comment77113791_45019842) from an old Podio support person.

If you are looking to remove fields from the query to reduce your datasource size within Klipfolio, I would recommend returning the API call in CSV format instead of JSON. Klipfolio support documents how to do this [HERE](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/215546958-Creating-a-Podio-Data-Source#:%7E:text=If%20you%20would%20like%20to,At%20Method%2C%20select%20GET.) by performing a GET operation and adding /csv to the end of the URL.

```
https://api.podio.com/item/app/Your-APP-ID/csv/
```

Comment: Kindly let me know, how to remove fields with this query to reduce size in klipfolio. After pagination Mapflat function is not working properly with huge datasets.

Comment: Sorry but is it not possible to remove fields from a Podio API call. What I would suggest is to set-up two different data sources. The first is in JSON format and determines how many records will be returned. The second is in CSV format and uses the count from the first data source to paginate through all the CSV records. You can add a limit of 500 records per page for the second data source. This should help. If you need more help, I suggest reaching out to Klipfolio support to give you an example in your account.

Comment: It is already done. But I have to fetch data of year which approx 50000+ rows. Mapflat function failed even 5000 data due to processing time.

Comment: Do you need to fetch all 50,000+ rows? Can you create a view for the app in Podio then use the following endpoint to only return the filtered items? https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/filter-items-by-view-4540284

If you still have too much data, then you need to set-up some sort of database with your Podio data and then connect Klipfolio to that.

Comment: Yeah, I need all rows, but don't need all column. That's why, I m searching any way to fetch only selected column.